# Opening Tabs In Newly Installed Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way I can save/backup my opened tabs in Firefox. For instance when my PC crashes, I would like the newly installed Firefox to open the tabs on the old Firefox.

So am asking if I can backup the tabs on my Firefox (like the way bookmarks can be backup) so that after installing a new one I can let it open the saved tabs.

Is it possible in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

The [xmarks](http://xmarks.com) extension [can synchronize](http://www.blogsdna.com/9202/xmarks-updated-now-supports-open-tabs-sync.htm) your open tabs with a remote server. Just install it on all of your Firefoxes and synchronize your tabs on exit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a HowToGeek tip that would help you,
[Quick Tip: Save Windows and Tabs When Restarting Firefox](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-save-windows-and-tabs-when-restarting-firefox/)
<sup>The `Startup` controls are in the first `'General'` tab these days and the default setting is "`Show my home page`".</sup>

[image]

There is also a firefox addon [`Bookmark Current Tab Set`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9027/) -- I'd keep a regular backup of the entire profile with this to completely recover firefox in case of a crash.

When running [firefox on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/12409/1352), I usually keep the profile backed-up all the time and run it off a ramdisk.

In general, backing up profile and frequent firefox restarts are useful to improve the firefox experience -- when you restart firefox all its previous process context is reset (your memory utilization figures get reset `:-)`.

Comment: That would not help if his *PC* crashes, as it does not itself synchronize the bookmark set with a remote location.

Comment: @whitequark, the idea would be to maintain a regular backup and restore from it in the event of a crash -- also check the askUbuntu reference I just added.